# Reference known property in (List<someClass>)someObject

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, data-processing

have tried some searches. Probably my lack of knowledge that I'm not using the right search terms or perhaps just not understanding the answers.

I have a method that is being passed an object, which I want to output a particular value to a text file.
I already know the object will be a **List< someClass >** of a few different possible classes (**customers/employees/items** etc). But all of the classes contain the same string property (e.g.) **string idNumber**.

So something like this:

```
public static void OutputFile(object myInput)
{
  foreach (someGenericObject in (List<anyType>)myInput)
  {
    string textToOutput = someGenericObject.idNUmber; 
    //output the text to somewhere else here
  }
}
```

I feel like as long as I know that it will always contain a this "idNumber" property regardless of the type, that I should be able to reference it somehow. But I just can't seem to get my head around it?

The error I typically get is something like:

> Cannot cast List< Employee > to List< object > etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have control over the definition of `Customer`, `Employee` and `Item`? As in, can you modify their definition? If so, you could have them all inherit from an interface with an `idNumber` property and change your method to be `public static void OutputFile(IEnumerable<IHasIdNumber> myInput)`.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great. I've posted that as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comments, if you have the ability to modify these classes, you can have them all inherit from an interface `IHasIdNumber` with an `idNumber` property.

Your method would then become:

```
public static void OutputFile(IEnumerable<IHasIdNumber> myInput)
{
  foreach (var item in myInput)
  {
    string textToOutput = item.idNUmber; 
    //output the text to somewhere else here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can solve this.

Recommended way: Implement common interface:

```
public interface INumberable { // I'm sure you can come up with a better name...
    string IDNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And then all the possible classes that can be passed into the method will implement `INumberable`. Your method can then look like this:

```
public static void OutputFile(List<INumerable> myInput)
{
  foreach (var someGenericObject in myInput)
  {
    string textToOutput = someGenericObject.idNUmber; 
    //output the text to somewhere else here
  }
}
```

Not-so-recommended way: Reflection:

```
Type t = someGenericObject.GetType();
var p = t.GetProperty("idNumber");
string theStringYouWant = (string)p.GetValue(someGenericObject);
```

Note that this is not very safe.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [dynamic].

```
foreach (var someGenericObject in (dynamic)myInput)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: OP's list isn't a `List<object>` so s/he can't use this method.

Answer (score -2):

If all your classes have the same property you want to access in foreach loop you can do in via interface.

```
public interface ISmth {
        int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student : ISmth {
        public int MyProperty { get;  set; }
    }

    public class Employee : ISmth {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

public static void DoSmth(object myObj) {
        foreach(ISmth item in (List<object>)myObj) {
            Console.Write(item.MyProperty);
        }
    }


List<Student> stdList = new List<Student>();

DoSmth(stdList.Cast<object>().ToList());
```

Comment: oops sorry try this:  foreach(ISmth item in (List<object>)myObj) {
                Console.Write(item.MyProperty);
            }

Comment: That will also throw a runtime error. How about testing the code?

Comment: It works fine if the list is a `List<object>`. If it's a `List<Student>` or `List<Employee>` (like OP said it would be), it will throw a runtime error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to convey with that link, but here, look, runtime error: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VH8PkZ

Comment: Convert your lists of Employee/students to list of objects DoSmth(stdList.Cast<object>().ToList());   (add using System.Linq;)

Comment: Yeah, you could do that, but there are much better ways to go about this that don't require a whole bunch of casting. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47279396/1945651) or [sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47279418/1945651), for instance.